# How to get rid of dual boot and Windows Boot Manager safely

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd

In the past, when I migrated to Win10 from WinXP, I created a dual boot for safety. The boot manager was installed on XP HDD and Win10 was installed on a new separate SSD. Still works great.

Now, I don't need this dual boot any longer but I do want to keep the Win10 SSD with all the setting. Is it possible? When I disconnect the old HDD where the boot manager is installed, the computer doesn't know how to boot. What should I do to make that Win10 SSD partition become bootable by itself without needing old XP boot manager? Is it even possible or do I face complete re-install of Win10?

Comment: Have you tried booting form W10 install disk and doing a boot repair?

Comment: yes, I get a blue screen with an error which indicates that I need to use recovery tools, however trying to repair results in "can't repair".

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do this with Windows tools but I am not as familiar with those. IMO depending on your comfort level, it may be just as easy to go ahead and install GRUB over the Win bootloader temporarily. GRUB is a linux bootloader, compatible with Windows. It would find all Windows installs on your system and add a boot entry automatically. Then next update or boot repair would overwrite GRUB with a fresh Win bootloader. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: I'd like to do this with Windows tools

Comment: Fair enough :) You need to reinstall the bootloader on the new W10 disk.  Ah, have you set the W10 disk to bootable in diskmgmt.msc (Disk Management) and then change boot order in BIOS to boot W10 first? If you do that and boot into a W10 install disk to do startup repair I think it may fix it.

Comment: Right, this is exactly my question - how do  I make the W10 disk bootable. I look into diskmgmt.msc, it has an option to "Mark partition as Active". Is that it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes that is it! :) Let me know if it works for u. If not, we can explore other avenues

Comment: I thought so.., I was afraid doing this because if I will make W10 active that will automatically make the XP HDD partition not active which will probably destroy the boot manager on it.. Which may result in my computer not booting at all if something doesn't work. So I kind of paused here.

Comment: I don't see why it would delete your xp boot partition. I don't think it would even touch it.

Comment: @Kyle H, thank you for bearing with me!  
I read warnings somewhere that because only one partition can be active, it will "deactivate" the other partition which I presumed not safe. Wrongly? Anyway, suppose I activate the Win10 partition now and restart, will I be able then to create the boot record on that disk with a recovery disk? Is this theoretical or this is what definitely should happen..

Comment: The other partition will deactivate because you are activating another to boot from. The other partition will still exist on disk but you will be able to boot W10 and still see your XP partitions. In the W10 bootloader you will be able to add your XP install to boot from.

Comment: @Kyle, you are a star! 
It all works now. Boots from W10 from SSD like a champion. Legacy HDD is doing fine too. You should make this as an answer so that I can accept and upvote this.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I put the main answer below. Please let me know if i should tweak it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to set your W10 partition as active in diskmgmt.msc first. Then you will be able to boot into W10 and your disk with xp will still be accessible.